# How to limit multiple requests from same IP? (Centos + APACHE)

Tags: apache, web-crawler, limit, block

I run wiki like database website. Some people crawl (scrape) my website data regularly.
So I am trying to block these crawlers.

Is there a script to prevent after certain number of requests from same IP address?

Comment: you need to say what kind of web server, platform or system and language you're using. Otherwise the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are modules like **mod_security** and **mod_evasive** in apache to prevent these kind of attack like scraping and DDOS.

You just need to install and configure it as you need for your server.

Check this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/amp/) for apache and CentOS configuration.